# How do I check a UILabel text against a string value?

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, uilabel

*I'm not a very experience coder so I am having difficulty figuring out if it's possible and if so how to check the string found in a label against a given string value.*

I want my Add button to be enabled when the Radius Label says something other than *"Radius in feet"* and when my Message Text Field is NOT empty.

So far I have:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    addButton.enabled = !radiuslabel.text == "Radius in feet" && !messageTextField.text.isEmpty
}
```

This code is wrong and I have been unable to find an answer. The Radius label is being given information from a slider.
This is the code for the slider function:

```
  @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    radiusLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

Is there another way to write this that keeps the Radius as a Integer while part of the Label?

Comment: `addButton.enabled = radiuslabel.text! != "Radius in feet" && messageTextField.text?.isEmpty == false`

Comment: Keep the sender parameter `sender: UITextField`

Comment: @LeoDabus You should probably just answer it at this point...my only complaint being the unnecessary unwrap of the first `text`

Comment: @SantaClaus I didn't test it as I was writing it on my phone so I wasn't sure it wasn't needed. I usually prefer to unwrap the text property using guard.

Comment: @LeoDabus If you answer I'll delete mine and upvote yours since I basically stole the optional chaining part of your solution...or yeah guard let is even better...

Comment: @SantaClaus No need to delete your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose your slider has value between `1 to 10` and `2` represent the value in `Feet`

so according to your code, you are setting the value in radiusLabel when slider value change

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    radiusLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
}
```

**AND** changing the value in Message Label

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    addButton.enabled = !radiuslabel.text == "Radius in feet" && !messageTextField.text.isEmpty
}
```

You are actually enabling the button when the value of `messageTextField` change

**What you want is** to enabled the button as soon as slider value set to feet or messageLabel has some value. You need to do is

```
func shouldEnableButton()
{
    //Assuming value 2 means value in feet
    addButton.enabled = radiuslabel.text != "2" && (messageTextField.text != nil && !messageTextField.text!.isEmpty)
}

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
    radiusLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
    messageLbl.text = nil
    self.shouldEnableButton()
}

@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    self.shouldEnableButton()
}
```

Comment: I do not have a text field corresponding to the Radius. I only have a slider and a label for it. My label was created using the Interface Builder with the starting value being "Radius in Feet". I wrote a function to change it when the slider is moved.

Comment: So whats the problem actually? Go with the code, you just need to enabled the button as per your label text.

Comment: While using your solutions. The Add Button does not enable

Comment: You need to call the code method everytime you change the slider or the messagelbl

Comment: Please explain what you mean by this. Individually I have a Radius Slider with a Label and a Message Text Field. The Message Text Field must not be empty and the Radius Slider must be moved for the Add button in the navigation bar to be enabled.

Comment: As per your updated code, your radiusLabel will have the value of UISlider which is on Int type and you are converting that int to string, so your RadiusLabel will never be equal to "Radius in feet". that why it is not enabled

Comment: Thank you. This works in the app but the message must be written before the slider is moved. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: If u r talking about the methods, it doesn't matter which come first and second, but if u are talking about messagelbl becomes nil just set nil in slidervaluechange method, I've updated my answer

Comment: The new code clears the message text field when the slider value changes. Since the radius slider is in the cell above the Message text field I want the radius to be changed and then the message. With the previous code, you had to write a message then change the slider.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying but it doesnt matter what change first, the thing is enabling the button is calling in the end. But you can change the text whichever change first as per your need.

Comment: Thank You. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the logical NOT (`!`) operator in front of radiusLabel.text. You instead want to use the "not equal to" operator (`!=`).

In addition, you should use optional chaining on the `UILabel` member `text` in the second occurrence (as you are accessing member `isEmpty`). Compare to false here since it is an optional.

```
addButton.enabled = radiuslabel.text != "Radius in feet" && messageTextField.text?.isEmpty == false
```

`sender` should remain of type `UILabel`

---

[More about operators in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

Comment: I tried this I received this error: "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"  I have attempted to not put anything in front of the radiusLabel before and received the same error. I put the logical NOT operator there because I was unsure of what the error meant.

Comment: @K.Airewele I did update my answer, but most of the credit must go to the commenter above, Leo Dabus

Comment: The Build Succeeds but the Add Button is not enabled after I move the slider and type the message

Answer (score -1):

Try below line of code:

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
addButton.enabled = (!(radiuslabel.text == "Radius in feet") && !messageTextField.text.isEmpty)
}
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: I tried this line and received the following error: "Optional type 'String?' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '== nil' instead"

Comment: No I am receiving a new error message now. "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: The Build Succeeds but while in the app, moving the slider and typing in the text box do not enable the button

Comment: `@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField)`
is above method called?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Put the debug  `@IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(sender: UITextField)`in this method. And check method is called or not.